Power Query cannot convert list and table error
I’m trying to copy some tables into a single table, the addresses are held in a table called DataSource. I’m using the code below but getting an error where the expression error, value is mismatched so is not putting the table together here is my code:
let
    // Step 1: Load the DataSource table
    DataSourceTable = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="DataSource"]}[Content],

    // Step 2: Check if the table is empty
    IsTableEmpty = Table.IsEmpty(DataSourceTable),

    // Step 3: Extract the column containing the paths if the table is not empty
    WorkbookPaths = if IsTableEmpty then {} else Table.Column(DataSourceTable, "file path"),

    // Helper function to load worksheet data from a given file path (URL) with error handling
    LoadWorksheet = (url as text) as table =>
        let
            Source = try Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents(url)) otherwise #table({}, {}),
            WorkbookData = if Source[HasError] then #table({}, {}) else Source[Value],
            // Select the sheet named "Data"
            Sheet = Table.SelectRows(WorkbookData, each [Kind] = "Sheet" and [Name] = "Data"),
            // Check if the sheet exists and extract data if it does
            SheetData = if Table.IsEmpty(Sheet) then #table({}, {}) else Sheet{0}[Data]
        in
            SheetData,

    // Step 4: Load and combine all worksheets into a single table if paths are available
    CombinedTable = if IsTableEmpty then #table({}, {}) else List.Accumulate(
        WorkbookPaths, 
        Table.FromRecords({}), 
        (state, current) => Table.Combine({state, LoadWorksheet(current)})
    )
in
    CombinedTable

I have tried changing it around but I’m very new to this, any help is appreciated

Where would I put otherwise? Thanks

As I understand if you use otherwise here: Source = try Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents(url)) otherwise #table({}, {}) then  you do not need next statement: WorkbookData = if Source[HasError] then #table({}, {}) else Source[Value]   Moreover it will not work properly. So try to delete this line. And reference in line “Sheet=..” directly on Source

I would suggest to refactor your code:
let // Step 1: Load the DataSource table 
DataSourceTable = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="DataSource"]}[Content],

// Step 2: Remove empty lines
RemoveEmpty = Table.SelectRows(DataSourceTable, each not ([file path] is null)),

// Helper function to load worksheet data from a given file path (URL) with error handling
LoadWorksheet = (url as text) as table =>
    let
        Source = Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents(url)),
        // Select the sheet named "Data"
        SheetData = Source{[Kind] = "Sheet", [Name] = "Data"}[Data]
    in
        SheetData,

// Step 3: Load all worksheets into a additional column 
AddTableColumn = Table.AddColumn(RemoveEmpty, “Data”, each try LoadWorksheet([file path]) otherwise #table({}, {})),

// Step 4: Combine all worksheets
CombinedTable = Table.Combine(AddTableColumn[Data])
in CombinedTable

